# Is there a way to have dlls not show up in the build file but are still used in a c# console app?

Tags: c#, .net, console

I'm not sure if its possible but I hope it it so my application can look more clean in the folder!

Comment: Please tag if your application is .NET Framework or .NET Core (or .NET 5)

Comment: I'm using .NET Framework by the way, I'm not use if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Single file applications have been available since .NET Core 3 and later enhanced in .NET 5.

Be warned that self-contained exes can be quite large since it will include the runtime and the framework libraries.

You can deploy your application as a single file by changing the deployment mode to `Self-contained` and checking `Produce single file` in the Visual Studio Publish Profile settings.

[image: VS Publisher Self-contained exe]

You can read more about single file applications [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file).